# JFrog Artifactory Basic Authentication

Tags: artifactory

We are planning to configure a CDN in front of a JFrog Artifactory repository, hosting zip files for download.

It seems that enabling "basic authentication" would be a nice solution. The CDN supports that.

A problem is that all requests are redirected to "ui/native":

https://mydomain.jfrog.io/artifactory/myrepo ->
https://mydomain.jfrog.io/ui/native/myrepo

When that occurs, if authentication is required, it shows a Login Page.   Probably that's wrong. Usually "basic auth" would show a pop-up asking for username and password.

1. In JFrog Cloud, how do I disable the redirect to ui/native?
2. If the redirect is disabled, what format will authentication take?  Will "basic auth" be in-effect then?  (Assuming that anonymous access has been removed.)